# Can not get clojure-contrib to load - FileNotFoundException

Tags: clojure

I have tried putting clojure-contrib.jar various places on my filesystem, I have tried manually specifying the classpath when launching the REPL, I have tried extracting the jar and putting the clj files on the classpath, nothing seems to work. I continue getting something like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/str_utils__init.
class or clojure/contrib/str_utils.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

When I execute `(println (seq (.getURLs (java.lang.ClassLoader/getSystemClassLoader))))` to see the classpath, it does include clojure-contrib:

```
(#<URL file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.6.0_06/lib/clojure-1.0.0.
jar> ... #<URL file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.6.0_06/lib/clojure-contrib.jar>)
```

When I make a .clj file of my own and put it on the classpath I am able to use or require it and have access to its functions as I'd expect.

If I move a .clj file - str-utils.clj for instance - to the pwd (which is on the classpath) it sorta works - it at leasts finds the file, although it generally can't do anything with it because of dependencies on other functions buried in clojure-contrib which it can't find.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work for clojure-contrib?

Comment: Are you running Clojure from commandline or an IDE?  If from commandline, post the exact command you're using to start it.  What version of Clojure are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you compiled your own clojure-contrib jar, you probably used the main branch which is not 1.0 compatible.

Follow the [Using clojure-contrib with Clojure 1.0](http://wiki.github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/using-together-with-clojure-100) doc to checkout the 1.0 tagged revision of clojure-contrib.

There is also a [clojure-contrib git branch](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/tree/clojure-1.0-compatible) that maintains 1.0 compatibility.