# Cannot get clojure-contrib sql to load - FileNotFoundException

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

I installed clojure and clojure contrib manually, through homebrew and mac ports all of them gives me this error.
I can get other parts to work.
What gives?

*edit*
this question seems similar
[Can not get clojure-contrib to load - FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825843/can-not-get-clojure-contrib-to-load-filenotfoundexception)
However i can load some parts, and i install through ports/brew so the versions should be in sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use clojure & clojure-contrib not directly, but through some project, for example, managed by [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) - it will fetch correct versions of clojure & clojure-contrib, plus some other dependencies that you're specify.  You can also look onto [my Lein introduction article](http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureLein.html) on this topic

Answer (score 1):

Well I couldn't make it work through fiddling with jars or using macport or homebrew.
But leiningen solved the problem for me.
To see the solution i came up with see:
https://github.com/khebbie/PET
also this article helped a lot:
http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-07/create-unix-services-with-clojure